# cannot open WSMLink

Tags: system-modeler

I'm evaluating Wolfram SystemModeler and I want to explore its capabilities together
with Mathematica. Unfortunately, I don't manage to get WSMLink working. In the notebook I'm using I typed

```
Needs["WSMLink`"]
```

and pressed Shift+Enter. Mathematica gives me this error message:

> Get::noopen: Cannot open
>   C:\Users\Carlo\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications\WSMLink\Config.m.
>    WSMLink::cconf: -- Message text not found -- (C:\Users\Carlo\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications\WSMLink\Config.m)

I'm new to Mathematica and I don't know where I can start fixing my problem.
I checked and the file C:\Users\Carlo\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications\WSMLink\Config.m does not exist on my computer.
Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Hi Carlo, Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I'm afraid I don't have much experience with WSM myself (just downloaded an evaluation copy a couple of months ago, and it's expired now). Given the path name I gather you're on Windows. Did you follow the normal installation procedures and did you use the suggested paths?

Comment: Thanks Sjoerd, I used the suggested paths but as  halirutan pointed out below it seems something with my configuration...

Answer (score 7):

> I work with development of SystemModeler at Wolfram Research

**Update:** WSM 3.0.1 which fixes this [has been released](http://www.wolfram.com/system-modeler/quick-revision-history.html).

This is an issue when using a combination of SystemModeler and a trial version of Mathematica. Unfortunately it is not easily fixed, so you will have to wait for an update to SystemModeler which will include the fix.

Comment: You are right, I have a trial version of SystemModeler and Mathematica...
I understand it cannot be easily fixed, but is there a workaround? What I really need is to evaluate are the capabilities of SystemModeler when I use it from Mathematica.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no workaround that can be applied by you, short of buying Mathematica.